# What's the simplest way to locate a host listener, in Android?

Tags: android, bonjour

I have an app that needs to find a specific host/port on a local network.  I would like to find something like bonjour that sits on a computer on a network and notifies whoever cares where they are, and a companion library for Android that I can use to locate this caller. 
Does something like this exist? I can't seem to find it, but perhaps I'm just not wording my search term usefully.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am building an app that discover a hardware IP/Port via Bonjour service. For that purpose, the Android app uses [jmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) which support Zero-Conf/Bonjour specs via Multicast. If your service end is already implementing Bonjour service, you could use the library to locate it. If you haven't gotten your Service registered, [the following Quick Tutorial on jmDNS](http://home.heeere.com/tech-androidjmdns.html) should be able to get you going.

It works by sending a Multicast message and the class that is trying to discover the service is implementing [ServiceListener](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/jmdns/ServiceListener.html) that listens when the Service is added/removed/resolved. Once the service is resolved you can get the [ServiceInfo](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/jmdns/ServiceInfo.html) from the [ServiceEvent.getInfo](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/jmdns/ServiceEvent.html#getInfo%28%29) which contains both host and port

Comment: cool, thanks I'll look into it... leaving the question opened for another day to see if anyone else chimes in with advice